# ANSWERED - Flutter install on Win11 - Error when running "flutter doctor"

Tags: windows, flutter, installation

**EDIT**

Problem is in the installation bundle flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable.zip installation file on the official page.
Use git to clone latest stable version instead by running the following code in the chosen install directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
```

Now running "flutter doctor" gives no errors.

**Original Question**

I have installed flutter by download the zip file from their official website, and when trying to run "flutter doctor" I keep getting errors.

First error before rinning "flutter pub get in flutter_tools:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Next Error:

```
Failed to find the latest git commit date: VersionCheckError: Command exited with code 128: git -c
log.showSignature=false log HEAD -n 1 --pretty=format:%ad --date=iso
Standard out:
Standard error: fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Returning 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000 instead.
```

Flutter error in doctor summary:

```
[!] Flutter (Channel unknown, 0.0.0-unknown, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1105], locale en-DK)
    ! Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown on channel unknown at C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\flutter
    ! Upstream repository unknown
```

Flutter path:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\flutter\bin

System Enviromental Variable:
User Variables -> Path -> "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\flutter\bin"

Flutter Doctor accepts all other parts, such as android toolchain, android studio ...
I have so far not come across a solution, and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the installation bundle flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable.zip file on the official page.
Use git to clone latest stable version instead by running the following code in the chosen install directory:

`git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable`

Now running "flutter doctor" gives no errors.